# personal logo on cv or label?

Tags: resume

I have a professional logo that was developed using my name and can be found as the banner on my website.  Is it appropriate to use it in the header of a cover letter for a blind mailing seeking a teaching position at a university?  Should I limit it only the address label which is a smaller scale for my return address?

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As-is, it's tough to say anything but 'it depends' to your question as we don't know the logo, the design, the position, etc. Even if we had that information, it would be difficult to predict what a potential employer will think of it. Why do you think this will be a problem to use, or why do you think it will be a benefit to use? What is your hesitation? What problem are you trying to solve? Clarifying those things will help us provide an answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

It may be appropriate. I certainly don't think it is inappropriate.
If it is **important to you** and you have a **compelling reason** to do so, go ahead.

Personally, if I was the one receiving the letter, I would find that strange. If you are seeking a position in any company (University or any other businesses) you are dropping your personal brand and assuming that company's brand. You are making a proposal to put your skills to their service under their flag, under their brand.

I would use that logo if I were to look for a position as a free-lancer professional, or if I were seeking a position in design (in which case it would be a logo I would have designed for myself).

The most important thing is: ask yourself what you would think if you were in the position of the recipient of that letter. Ask yourself what is the compelling reason to adding your logo - what is it that you are trying to achieve. If you cannot find an actual (professional) reason for it (that would add more value to your worth for that position), there is your answer.

Comment: It also depends on the type and level of your accomplishments associated with that logo, and whether these accomplishments are relevant to the position in question.

Comment: @La-comadreja no, the name of the legal entity would then suffice. Or are you suggesting to put the corporate logo of every company you ever worked for on your resume (which would likely not be legal)?

Answer (score 1):

Would the company be hiring the person or the persona?

If you have a website that generates a nice amount of traffic and has some interesting things on it, you should definitely include the link, especially if you coded / designed it yourself.

That said I don't think it's a good idea to put the banner in the header, or in any other field of the CV. No one wants to hire John "user16930" Doe, unless he's "the" man for the job (and said job can't be done by anyone else, something quite rare these days). So unless you're Rambo and the job is to infiltrate a Vietnamese compound, I'd say stay away from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it as any more of an issue than the logos that staffing companies sometimes add to the top of your resume when they reformat it into their style.